# How to create SPF with many CIDR ranges, like _spf.google.com

Tags: email-validation, spf

How can I create a TXT value of a SPF like Google SPF _spf.google.com

I want to create a value which I can put in my spf like _spf.mydomainname.com then spf value will be

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.mydomainname.com -all
```

WHen I put above value in my SPF it will call all the CIDR IP ranges to authorise to send mail.
LIke google spf  _spf.google.com has many cidr ranges and then at the end it call google IP netblock and so on.

The above spf has below values and include have mulitple IP

```
v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all
```

way to achive multiple spf looping

Comment: You're asking how to nest SPF records? You basically create an additional SPF TXT record at _netblocks.mydomainname.com that includes the IP ranges you want to add and include that SPF TXT record in your main SPF TXT record at the root of your sending domain. Or is your question about how to dynamically list all your IP ranges to your SPF?